# How to filter by value calculated in renderer function magento

Tags: magento

may be someone knows how to filter product grid by returned value from renderer.

In Grid.php I have:

```
 protected function _prepareCollection() {
    $collection->joinField( 'qty', 'cataloginventory/stock_item', 'qty', 'product_id=entity_id', '{{table}}.stock_id=1', 'left' );


$collection->joinTable( 'cataloginventory/stock_item','product_id=entity_id', array("stock_status" => "is_in_stock", "plan") )
 ->addAttributeToSelect('stock_status')
 ->addAttributeToSelect('plan');

protected function _prepareColumns() {
$this->addColumn( 'qty', 
            array(
                'header' => Mage::helper( 'catalog' )->__( 'Qty' ), 
                'width' => '30px', 
                'type' => 'number', 
                'index' => 'qty',
                'renderer'      =>      new TBT_Enhancedgrid_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid_Plan(),
            ) );

}
```

In Plan.php

```
 public function render(Varien_Object $row) {
    $value = $row->getData('qty');
     if (is_numeric($value))
            {
                $value = round($value, 2);
            }
    $value1 = $row->getData('plan');
     if (is_numeric($value1))
            {
                $value1 = round($value1, 2);
            }
    $value3 = $value/$value1;
    $valuepr = number_format( $value3 * 100, 2 ) . '%';
    return '<strong>К: </strong>'.$value. '<br/>'.'<strong>P: </strong>'.$value1.'<br/>'.'<strong>Z: </strong>'.$value2.'<br/>'.'<strong>Pr: </strong>'.$valuepr;    
        }
}
```

It works fine and display result I need, but how I can filter in grid by value, which have been get in $valuepr?
Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter collection by `$valuepr` then it has to be in the collection itself. At the moment you are computing it outside of your collection in the `render()` method.

In order to do so, you would need to amend collection in the `_prepareCollection()`  method. This could be similar to the following code (please note that I am not able to test this, so it is more a hint than a ready-to-go solution):

`protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    // current collection settings goes here`

```
$collection->getSelect()
    ->columns(
        array(
            'value_pr' => new Zend_Db_Expr(
                'ROUND(ROUND(table_prefix_1.qty, 2) / ROUND(table_prefix_2.plan, 2), 2)'
            )
        )
    );
```

}

where `table_prefix_1` is a prefix of first `cataloginventory/stock_item` table and `table_prefix_2` is a prefix of second stock_item table. If you want to know what prefixes those tables have you can log the SQL query, e.g.:

`Mage::log($collection->getSelect()->assemble(), null, 'sql.log');
// or
$collection->load(false, true);`

The first one will log the SQL query into sql.log file. You will find it in `var/log` folder of your Magento instance. This, however will not work fine with EAV collections like products, categories or customers. That's why I provided second way of checking the SQL. You can provide 2 parameters into collection's `load()` method. First one is a flag tells whether to display the query before running it against database and second one is a flag which tells whether to log the query into system.log.

Please note that you can filter a grid column only by one value. You cannot filter column `qty` by quantity and value_pr at the same time. You have to decide which one you want to use. You can always make it into separate columns.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately filtering not work, I receive error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in www\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abstract.php on line 816. And as I understand this function check if value is in DB